# Function runs when form is empty

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I am trying to create a form where if the form is not filled-in, the function passed will not do submit. But with the code below, whenever the form is empty, the function will still run.

```js
const ELS_pages = document.querySelectorAll(".page");
const ELS_buttons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-page]");

console.log(ELS_pages);
const submit = document.querySelector(".submit");
const goToPage = (id) => {
  ELS_pages.forEach((EL) => EL.classList.toggle("u-none", EL.id !== id));
};

ELS_buttons.forEach((EL) =>
  EL.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(EL.dataset.page);
    goToPage(EL.dataset.page);
  })
);
const myForm = document.querySelector("#form-id");
const name = document.querySelector("#name");
const pin = document.querySelector("#pin");
myForm.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (name.value !== "" && pin.value !== "") {
    console.log("white");
    // submit.dataset.page = settings;
    submit.addEventListener("click", function () {
      goToPage(submit);
    });
  } else {
    alert("you need to input");
  }
});
```

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
}
nav a {
  color: #00f;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Utility classes */
.u-none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="page" id="page-login">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <button type="button" data-page="page-main">ENTER</button>
  </div>

  <div class="page u-none" id="page-main">
    <nav>
      <a data-page="page-settings">User Settings</a>
      <a data-page="page-login">Logout</a>
    </nav>
    <h1>MAIN PAGE</h1>
    <form action="" id="form-id">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" />
      <label for="pin">Pin</label>
      <input type="text" id="pin" />
      <button type="submit" class="submit" data-page="page-settings">
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="page u-none" id="page-settings">
    <nav>
      <a data-page="page-main">Back to Main</a>
      <a data-page="page-login">Logout</a>
    </nav>
    <h1>SETTINGS PAGE</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first question is, why you don't use `required` into input? and another question is why you put `addEventListener` of submit button into `addEventListener` of submit form?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini okay for the required, I am trying to create a situation where I have a home page, the home page leads to a login form then when the user logs in the login form display is set to none and then the main page opens up, I am not using a backend for it. The submit button links to the next page when the form is submitted

Comment: I think it should work.
Are you not able to see alert?
https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-haslett-v2hu5?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @Nitesh yes it runs and that is what I am trying to avoid, my main aim is                            1. On page load main page displays
2. On click on main page, the form displays and main page display is set to none                 3. When form is filled, login page display is nome and the dashboard like is then displayed. do you get my logic here?

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this :

HTML :

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="page" id="page-login">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <button type="button" data-page="page-main">ENTER</button>
  </div>

  <div class="page u-none" id="page-main">
    <nav>
      <a data-page="page-settings">User Settings</a>
      <a data-page="page-login">Logout</a>
    </nav>
    <h1>MAIN PAGE</h1>
    <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="" id="form-id">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="fname" />
      <label for="pin">Pin</label>
      <input type="text" id="pin" name="fname1"/>
      <button type="submit" class="submit">
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="page u-none" id="page-settings">
    <nav>
      <a data-page="page-main">Back to Main</a>
      <a data-page="page-login">Logout</a>
    </nav>
    <h1>SETTINGS PAGE</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
nav {
  display: flex;
}
nav a {
  color: #00f;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Utility classes */
.u-none {
  display: none;
}
```

JS

```
const ELS_pages = document.querySelectorAll(".page");
const ELS_buttons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-page]");

console.log(ELS_pages);
const submit = document.querySelector(".submit");
const goToPage = (id) => {
  ELS_pages.forEach((EL) => EL.classList.toggle("u-none", EL.id !== id));
};

ELS_buttons.forEach((EL) =>
  EL.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log(EL.dataset.page);
    goToPage(EL.dataset.page);
  })
);
const myForm = document.querySelector("#form-id");
const name = document.querySelector("#name");
const pin = document.querySelector("#pin");




function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
   var x1 = document.forms["myForm"]["fname1"].value;
  if (x == "" || x == null || x1 == "" || x1 == null ) {
 
    return false;
  }
}
```

I just added validateForm() function to be check in onsumbit in your form

And now when you click Sumbit on your page when name and pin are empety - the form don't do anything
[image]

Comment: what I am trying to avoid, my main aim is 1. On page load main page displays 2. On click on main page, the form displays and main page display is set to none 3. When form is filled, login page display is nome and the dashboard like is then displayed. do you get my logic here?

Comment: i do exacly what you need.. Don;t understand what is bad here now? You wanted to check if name and pin is empety then when you click submit there don't do anything - here you go.

Comment: sorry my questions may be a little bit not clear, I am a newbie and interpreting my thought is quite difficult for me at the moment. I haven’t tried this code out yet, my system just shut down for some weird reasons. But From your solution if the form is not filled and still submitted would it still link to the dashboard like page? Or just stay alert? From your code I don’t understand how I’d implement my next step which is for the form to link to the dashboard like page on submit and login page should be set to display none